# CSS form for emailing the data not working

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am working on a website and the form in the code is not working up. What can I do to make it work and put it in action. Here is the form code....

```
        <div class="form"; action="mail.php"; method="post">
        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="name" value="Your Name         *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"     onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="Your E-    mail *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
        <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="message" cols="0" rows="0" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Your Message *</textarea>
        <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="send message">
        </div>
```

Here is the PHP code I am using to fetch data from form.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'myemail@example.com';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
empty($_POST['email']) ||
empty($_POST['message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if (!preg_match(
"/ ^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
$email_address))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}
if( empty($errors))
{
$to = '$myemail';
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
    "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
?>
```

The problem is that after entering data in the form, it is not proceeding any further.

Comment: You must have an opening and closing form tag, like,  `<form class="form"; action="mail.php"; method="post">

Answer (score 1):

Change the markup so that it is a `<form>` not a `<div>` and get rid of the semicolons.

```
<form class="form" action="mail.php" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a Lot :)